# How can I install .NET 2.0

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I am using Windows 7 and .NET 4.0.

When I try to install the Azure platform, it says I need .NET 2.0.

So I install .NET 2.0. This install fails because it says .NET 2.0 is already installed on the OS.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Which package are you trying to install?

Comment: try the Azure forums...http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsazureplatform/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in Control Panel->Add Remove Programs->Add Remove Windows Features.  According to Microsoft documentation it's listed in there.  Having said that, Windows 7 comes with .Net 2.0 already installed as part of the OS.

Comment: Windows 7 control panel has "Programs and Features", not "Add/Remove Programs".

Comment: Oops, you're correct.

Comment: Microsoft .NET framework 2.0 or 3.0 or 3.5 is not listed there.

Comment: Where is the Microsoft documentation?

Comment: @user55114 I was sure that I had a link from when I was working on a similar problem on Friday.  This is the closest I found:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/26/how-to-repair-the-net-framework-2-0-and-3-0-on-windows-vista.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an old version of the Azure toolkit?

If you have Visual Studio 2010 you can go to this link and let the Web Platform Installer install everything that is necessary: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=WindowsAzureToolsVS2010

Comment: No, I don't havet the Azure toolkit.

Comment: In fact, installing the Azure toolkit requires installing .NET 2.0 which fails